# Am I able to write to a file using a user defined function?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def writetofile():
    myFile = open("C:\Jazmyn\myText.txt", "a")
    myFile.write(a)
    myFile.close()

# creating new text file, I have created a folder named "Jazmyn"
# in my C drive and the text file is created there. 


def greenbottles():
    bottle = ['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten' ]
    text_one = 'green bottles hanging on the wall'
    text_two = 'And if one green bottle should accidentally fall\nThere\'ll be'


    for i in range(10, 0, -1):
        print(bottle[i], text_one)
        print(bottle[i], text_one)
        print(text_two, bottle[i-1], text_one)


greenbottles()
# this needs to be written to the file
```

I am new to python and I am finding it difficult. It is possible to make it so that the `greenbottles` code can be written to the new text file (myText) or can I fix the `print` statement so they write to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`print` takes a `file` keyword-only parameter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), so if you just need to write the values you are printing in your `for` loop to a file you can just open a file (or a file-like object) and pass it to print:

```
with open("your/file.ext", "a") as fo:
    print("Hello", file=fo)
    print("All this goes to fo", file=fo)
```

Comment: Do I modify the print statements with that current example or make it so it's a new print statement all together?

Comment: @JessicaSmith - you can modify your `print` calls - unless you need the output displayed on the screen as well - in which case you'll either need to duplicate your `print` calls or look into using the `logging` module.

Comment: Each individual print statement?, I've never done anything passing to a print before.

Comment: @JessicaSmith - yes, just like in the example I gave :-)  If you don't want to have to provide the `file` keyword argument each time you could use a closure to create a new function: `output_for_file = lambda f: lambda *args: print(*args, file=f)`

Comment: Which you would then use in this way:  `printer = output_for_file(fo)`  ... and later `printer("Hello", "this", "goes to the file!")`

Comment: I didn't entirely understand the using a closure part I must say, I am very new to python and still learning the bare bones. With open("C:\Jazmyn\myText.ext","a") as fo: Like this to start? I'm not sure what I put instead of "Hello" in that print statement, I apolgise in advance for misunderstanding, thanks for helping me.

Comment: @JessicaSmith - Spot on - then you can simply put the body of your `for` loop from `greenbottles` inside the `with` block and update them all to use `file=fo` :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to print to the text file! Now I need to make the last bit of the code with the one bottle/s without the s.